# Angular 2 function inside subscribe method getting called even before completion or request

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to get parameter from URL and then passing it to another method. Here is the code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getParamValues();
  }

 getParamValues() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {      
        this.checkUser(params);
    });
  }



  checkUser(params: any) {  
// Here this method i called twice first time with no params and second time with params
  }
```

This check Method will first check basically doing a check if user in session storage then load basic details from there else go to service.

So problem is my checkUser method is getting called twice and I just can not put a check of that params is empty or not as there is something else i am doing except this logic.

Is it possible that my check user method gets only called when subscribe method is done with the data not before?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the `subscribe` method that you're talking about?

Comment: was trying something and pasted the same code. updated now

Comment: @RaxWeber example you code worked when i provide param to that URL but  when my URL is with any param then my method is not getting called. It is because of Skip method.

Comment: Rahul's answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
getParamValues() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if (params) {
      this.checkUser(params);
    }
  });
}



checkUser(params: any) {  

}
```

**Update**

```
ngOnInit(){
  if(localStrorage.getItem('User')){
    // get user details
  } else {
    getParamValues();
  }
}
```

Comment: as i mentioned i cant put this check as something else i am doing in function and checkUser should be called only when params varibale is ready

Comment: @PraveenRawat can you tell what else you are doing may be that can be done. sorry i overlooked that line

Comment: i am checking if user is in sessionStorage then load details from there if not then as per param value it should be loaded from service.

Comment: ya i checked , sorry for the same.

Comment: @PraveenRawat updated the answer it can be achieved like this i hope

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not entirely certain I understand your issue - you can't check the params, but you can't run the checkuser function without the params? Why not:

```
getParamValues() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if (params) {
      this.checkUser(params);
    }
    // Other logic here
  });
}
```

Or, if you need to run checkUser regardless:

```
checkUser(params: any) {  
  if (params) { ... } else { ... }
}
```

Comment: my checkUser method is getting called twice first when subscribe is reading params and when it actually finished with reading. What I want is when subscribe is done with only then it should call method. It like finally method, when everything is loaded then it should execute